# Get all parents of xml-elment in ACE Editor Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, xml

Does anyone know whether it is possible to get all parents of an xml element in the ace editor or the xpath?

```js
this.editor.on("click", (e: any) => {
    const position = this.editor.getCursorPosition();
    const line = this.editor.getSession().getLine(position.row);

    console.log("test",line);
    const position = e.getDocumentPosition();

    const token = this.editor.session.getTokenAt(position.row, position.column);
    if (token && token.type === 'meta.tag.tag-name.xml') {
        const tagName = token.value;
        console.log(`Current XML tag name: ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
        console.log(`Current XML tag name: ${JSON.stringify(this.editor.session.getParentElement(tagName))}`);
    }
  });
```

with that code I am able to get the current xml tag